# Как сделать, чтобы блок был всегда по центру экрана?

Tags: html, css

как сделать, чтобы блок **main-block** был всегда по центру экрана, даже если уменьшили масштаб окна в браузере? Но адаптивность сохранилась.

```css
.title {
  margin: 10px auto 25px;
}

.block-row {
  margin: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  max-width: 700px;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  width: 320px;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-block">
  <h1 class="title">Tittle of this page</h1>
  <div class="block-row">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="block">
        some text in block
      </div>
      <div class="text-under">
        text there
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="box">
      <div class="block">
        some text in block
      </div>
      <div class="text-under">
        text there
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/yLBzaxX   так ?

Comment: @MaximLensky да!

Comment: @MaximLensky теперь появились горизонтальные полосы прокрутки, как от них избиваться? overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden; не помогают

Comment: сбросить margin и padding - я же там это сделал - либо код покажите

Answer (score -1):

Вот так

```
.main-block{padding:0px; margin:0px auto;}
```

Comment: так не работает

Comment: @Imp3l Попробуйте так .main-block{padding:0px!important; margin:0px auto!important;}

Comment: Все равно так же

Comment: @Imp3l  Попробуйте добавить  float: none!important;

Comment: я уже пытался по этому гайду делать https://frontender.info/centering-css-complete-guide/ и все равно не работает

Comment: @Imp3l Кэш браузера чистили?

Comment: чистил кэш, запускал в других браузерах. Ничего не работает